# Ebizmarts Mailchimp Can We Use Storewise In Magento2

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

I want to use `Ebizmarts_Mailchimp` store wise to know that which language site the subscription came from.

Also How to link the signup form in footer to Mailchimp and link checkout to record revenue.

I configure all API key in admin.

But I am confused that How it work.

Answer (score 0):

I work in Ebizmarts and I will be happy to help you out on this one.
There are a couple ways to be able to know where the subscription came from.

1. Create one list per language. This is usually what we recommend because it has the best compatibility with the full e-commerce synchronization.
2. Add interest groups and then force the subscription to a certain group when subscribing from each store view.

If you are not sure on how to do this please contact our support at **`mailchimp@ebizmarts-desk.zendesk.com`**.

Answer (score 0):

But we can select ONLY 1 list per new store, that is the problem.
How can we assign two or more  different lists and use it for each language?